# Set the last number in a string to negative

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have a string with diffrent mathematical characters, and i want to make the last number negative/positive. Let's say the string is "100/5*30-60+333". The result i want is "100/5*30-60+(-333)", and i want to convert it back to positive ("100/5*30-60+333").

```
function posNeg() {
  // hiddenText is a <input> element. This is not shown.
  let n = hiddenText.value;
  n.split('+');
  n.split('-');
  n.split('*');
  n.split('/');
  console.log(n);
}
```

What i get is the whole hiddenText.value, and not an array of all numbers. Any tips?

Comment: But... Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Would not that be essentially a non-op?  I don't understand the converting back part; just keep the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Let's say the string is "100/5*30-60+333". The result i want is
>   "100/5*30-60+(-333)", and i want to convert it back to positive
>   ("100/5*30-60+333").

The following code does that:

```
let mathStr = '100/5*30-60+333';
console.log(mathStr);
let tokens = mathStr.split('+');
let index = tokens.length - 1;
let lastToken = tokens[index];
lastToken = '('.concat('-', lastToken, ')');
let newMathStr = tokens[0].concat('+', lastToken);
console.log(newMathStr); // 100/5*30-60+(-333)
console.log(mathStr); // 100/5*30-60+333
```

EDIT:

> ...  and i want to convert it back to positive ("100/5*30-60+333").

One way is to declare `mathStr` (with the value "100/5*30-60+333") as a `var` at the beginning and reuse it, later as you need. Another way is to code as follows:

```
let str = "100/5*30-60+(-333)";
str = str.replace('(-', '').replace(')', '');
console.log(str); // 100/5*30-60+333
```

Answer (score 2):

First, I'd match all of the basic math operators to get their order:

```
const operatorsArr = n.match(/\+|\-|\/|\*/g)
```

Then, split the string:

```
function posNeg() {
  // hiddenText is a <input> element. This is not shown.
  let n = hiddenText.value;
  n = n.replace(/\+|\-|\/|\*/g, '|');
  n = n.split('|');
  console.log(n);
}
```

Then, you will have an array of numbers, in which you can mutate the last number easily:

```
n[n.lengh-1] *= -1;
```

Now we can combine the two arrays together:

```
let newArr;
for (let i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
  newArr.push(n[i]);
  if (operatorsArr[i]) newArr.push(operatorsArr[i]);
}
```

At last, you can rejoin the array to create the new String with a seperator of your choosing. In this example I'm using a space:

```
newArr = newArr.join(' ')
```

Please let me know how that works out for you.

Comment: I believe it is, since he said the problem is that the output of console.log is the full input value.

Comment: Editted the answer, I believe it answers his question now.

Answer (score 0):

To get numbers You can use replace function and split  check code bellow :

```
   function posNeg() {
  // hiddenText is a <input> element. This is not shown.
  let n = "100/5*30-60+333";
  n = n.replace('+','|+');
  n = n.replace('-','|-');
  n = n.replace('*','|*');
  n = n.replace('/','|/');
  n=n.split('|');console.log(n);
// to use any caracter from array use it in removeop like example 
// if we have array (split return) have 100 5 30 60 333 we get 100 for example 
// we need to make removeop(n[0]) and that reutrn 100;
// ok now to replace last value to negative in string you can just make 
// var lastv=n[n.length-1];
// n[n.length-1] ='(-'+n[n.length-1])+')';
//var newstring=n.join('');
//n[n.length-1]=lastv;
//var oldstring=n.join('');


}


function removeop(stringop)
{

  stringop = stringop.replace('+','');
  stringop = stringop.replace('-','');
  stringop = stringop.replace('*','');
  stringop = stringop.replace('/','');
return stringop;
}
```

Comment: Once you've split it, how do you put it back together?

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to add "()", then you can modify accordingly

```
<script>
function myConversion(){
  var str = "100/5*30-60-333";
  var p = str.lastIndexOf("+");

  if(p>-1)
  {
  str = str.replaceAt(p,"-");
  }
  else
  {
  var n = str.lastIndexOf("-");
  if(n>-1)
  str = str.replaceAt(n,"+");
  }
  console.log(str);
}
String.prototype.replaceAt=function(index, replacement) {
    return this.substr(0, index) + replacement+ this.substr(index + replacement.length);  

}
</script>
```